# Determine if coordinates are in regions defined in a KML file

Tags: coordinates, kml, latitude-longitude, geography

I am looking for some way to determine if a given lat/long is within a polygon contained in a KML file. I know Google has some Maps APIs, but I need everything to be done offline and locally.

Ideally you would input the location, it would scan and calculate through the coordinates in the KML file, then it would output a yes or no depending on if the input was located within the region.

Comment: Do a Google search for `point in polygon test`.

Comment: Have a look at projects like [Proj.Net](http://projnet.codeplex.com/), [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial), [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite), [JTS Topology Suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/), [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/). Google for [Spatial predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM#Spatial_predicates)